# BigQuery casting int64 to uint64

Tags: google-bigquery

I am storing uint64 as INTEGER type in bigquery (values > 2^63 become negative). Is there a way to cast it to it's correct value while querying bigquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a type which is big enough to hold UINT64, in BigQuery, the easy option is to use `NUMERIC` type. That said, I think the correct way to convert it back is through:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION int64_to_uint64(x INT64) AS
(IF (x < 0, 
     NUMERIC "18446744073709551616" /* 2^64 */ + x, 
     /* ELSE */ CAST(x AS NUMERIC)));

-- Check 2 boundaries:
SELECT int64_to_uint64(-1); -- returns 18446744073709551615, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
SELECT int64_to_uint64(-9223372036854775808); -- returns 9223372036854775808, 0x8000000000000000
SELECT int64_to_uint64(12345); -- positive number also works
```